# $f(x):S^{2n} \rightarrow S^{2n}$ continuous so that there is $x \in S^{2n}$ with $f(x)=x$ or $f(x)=-x$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $f:S^{2n}\rightarrow S^{2n}$ continuous. Then there is $x \in S^{2n}$ with $f(x)=x$ or $f(x)=-x$. I am having a hard time finding a starting Point. Thank you

Comment: I saw you tagged your question as (algebraic-topology), so maybe $S$ is some particular space I am not aware of, but if it is compact you can use some standard fixed-point theorem such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem. Also in the title of your question you write $f(x)=\pm x$; what does $\pm$ stand for? Do you mean $f$ is either $f(x)=x$ or $f(x)=-x$, or $f$ is a multi-valued function? You may also want to take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_fixed_point_theorem

Comment: MSorry it was unclear. I meant it is either  x or -x. And $S^{2n}=\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^{2n+1} | ||x||=1 \}$

Comment: It seems to me that this is a consequence of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem - See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $f$ doesn't have fixed point ($f(x) \neq x$ for all $x \in S^{2n}$). Then $f$ is homotopic to the antipodal map ($f(x)+(-x)\neq 0$, so homotopy is pretty obviuos here), so $\deg(f)=(-1)^{2n+1}=-1.$ On other side, if $f(x) \neq -x$ for all $x \in S^{2n}$, then $-f$ has no fixed point, so $\deg(-f)=-1$. But, we know that $\deg(-f)=-\deg(f)$, which implies that there must be some $x \in S^{2n}$ such that $f(x)= x$ or $f(x)=-x$.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is a consequence of the [hairy ball theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem) stating that that any continuous function that maps an even-dimensional sphere into itself has either a fixed point or a point that maps onto its own antipodal point. This is very well explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem#Corollary).